# Using Selenium to scrape the id_str object

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

Using the Selenium library in python, I am currently scraping content from a twitter search results page: https://twitter.com/search?q=twinkie&src=typd&lang=en

The Selenium library has the following functions to identify the content that we want to grab:

```
find_elements_by_name
find_elements_by_xpath
find_elements_by_link_text
find_elements_by_partial_link_text
find_elements_by_tag_name
find_elements_by_class_name
find_elements_by_css_selector
```

The particular object I want to grab is called id_str. It is a string of unique numbers that is specific to each account. I have been having a rather hard time figuring out how to grab this particular object.

Because of the length of each element, I won't bother copying all of the html code directly in here but I am noticing that all id_str is preceded by:

```
<div class="tweet js-stream-tweet js-actionable-tweet js-profile-popup-actionable dismissible-content
   original-tweet js-original-tweet


   has-cards  has-content
```

Which function would you suggest that I use to grab id_str. Optimally, I would like to have enough bearings with webpage codes that I will be able to identify other objects by myself-- what topics should I review to better understand? I am still relatively new to coding.

Thank you so much for reading everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to get the value of 'id_str' key in 'data-reply-to-users-json' attribute of the `div` element you shared, try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import ast

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://twitter.com/search?q=twinkie&src=typd&lang=en')
tweets = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'tweet js-stream-tweet js-actionable-tweet js-profile-popup-actionable dismissible-content')]")
for tweet in tweets:
    print(ast.literal_eval(tweet.get_attribute('data-reply-to-users-json'))[0]['id_str'])
```

This should print all the 'id_str' values.

Comment: Wow! It worked flawlessly. Thank you Kamal. Do you have any suggestions on a topic that I should learn to be better at this? I have been reading about html structures for instance

Comment: You can go through various examples of selenium code on the internet/stackoverflow and then search for specific topics if you don't understand in a code. I guess the best option is to keep coding like you are trying now and you will come across various topics eventually.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you know xpath, use xpath. Otherwise use css.

```
find_elements_by_css_selector('*[id_str]')
```

Comment: invalid search. Sorry

Comment: It might need a *  in there. Both ways are valid css though.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify as you are just after an existing attribute of user id from those tweets

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://twitter.com/search?q=twinkie&src=typd&lang=en')
tweets = [tweet.get_attribute('data-user-id') for tweet in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[data-reply-to-users-json]')]
print(tweets)
#driver.quit()
```